# Using rJava package on Shinyapps

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I have a small app that requires rJava as a dependency to send email using mailR package.

Unfortunately, when I try to deploy the app to Shinyapps, it throw an error and terminate with this error message:

```
error: Unhandled Exception: HTTP 599: Timeout during request
```

Is there any workarounad to use rJava on Shineyapps?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading "rJava", I simply loaded "mailR". It works fine, still no solution to load "rJava".